# Getting Rails error "syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' before_save :create_unique_profile_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make my users have a profile id when they create their account so I can create a profile page based on id. I do not want them to have a username. The problem is when I created a user it worked just fine, however when I edit the user information which is what I use on the profile page it gives me the error...

```
 syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' before_save :create_unique_profile_id
```

They sign up using email and passwords and when they go to edit they have more information, that isn't necessarily required, that they can edit/create. It shouldn't be trying to create a profile_id when submitting this. only upon sign_up.

This is my current code

```
before_save :create_unique_profile_id

def create_unique_profile_id
  while self.class.exists?(:profile_id => profile_id)
    begin
      self.profile_id=SecureRandom.base64(8)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I'm an idiot. I didn't put profile_id in strong params. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But the error has nothing to do with strong parameters. The error you give here is solved with my answer, isn't it?

Comment: I tried it both ways. Your solution made the code look better but really didn't effect how it worked. It was a strong_params issue in my controller. My coworker found it.